# Design advice for a very interactive rails account balancing app

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am porting an app that I wrote in Intersystems Caché language and am looking for Rails design advice.
Basically, I have a table of account transactions, and a second table of statement transactions that I previously parsed from a flat-file.
To reconcile/balance the account, I match each statement transaction with an account transaction (or add it on the fly), and store the respective ID's in the tables to show that it has been cleared.

In Caché, I would list the current statement transaction at the top of the page, and list all of the matching account transactions (with the same dollar amount) at the bottom.  A javascript on-click event would then pass the data to a Caché script that would update the database and then update the page with the next transaction, etc.

So as a more experienced Rails coder, what design would you recommend, given the large amount of interaction? The examples below are various ways I'm thinking of as a novice.

- Submit the page after each interaction and have it save the data
  to the tables and then reload with the next set of items to reconcile. I guess it would have to use parameters to keep track of the current position in the table.
- Simulate what Cache' does by using jQuery/AJAX (which I have only had brief exposure to) to pass the data back to Ruby and/or SQL script to update the tables. I think I would still need to use on-Click or on-Change listeners to trigger the actions.s

Except for a couple of experiments, I don't have code for this yet because I wanted to get advice before potentially painting myself into a corner.

Answer (score 0):

After much experimentation and more experience with the transfer of control back and forth between the server and the browser, I've gone with the get/post model because that seems to be how it is usually done in Rails.  It's a little outside my comfort zone coming from a procedural language, and it seems less efficient to rebuild an entire page rather than updating existing values/components of the page, but I'm sure with time, I'll understand more about why it's done that way.